# iOS: Localising to en-GB when australian language is set as language and australia as region

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

In iOS app localisation (`NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"key", @"Localizable", Bundle, nil);`) always localises to en-GB when australian English is set as language and australia as region and my app supports only en-US and en-GB,chinese,spanish on what basis iOS is returning en-GB? as default it should pick the first preferred and app supported language as per my undertanding

and in my phone settings , preferred languages are in the following order

1. English-Australia
2. Chinese
3. Spanish
4. English-US
5. English-UK

AS EN-AU IS NOT SUPPORTED by my app It should fallback to next supported preferred language Rt?

So as a result to Chinese language it should localise, but why I iOS is localising to en_GB ?

Comment: How are you testing it? Device or simulator?

Comment: What locale function are you using? Are you using `[NSLocale currentLocale]` OR `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]` or `[NSLocale systemLocale]`.. You haven't specified anything ={

Comment: I am using NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"key", @"Localizable", Bundle, nil);

Comment: I am testing on Device

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace 'en-US' with 'en' in localizations list. That way it should be default for all en-XX that are not supported.